2D ScrollView with horizontal and vertical sticky header
I am trying to develop a scheduling app as shown in this image.

Since the weekly schedule won't fit in a single page I am using a nested scroll view, one that scrolls vertically and another horizontally. However, when I start scrolling vertically I want the times along the side always to stay there and the same for the day of the week up top. Right now it seems like I can only get one or the other, is there any way to get both?
I've uploaded my code to this snack:
https://snack.expo.dev/@kojon74/funny-indigo-waffles
